# crontab not syncing up with AWS S3 bucket

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

- Platform: Amazon-Linux
- Other applications installed: php, php-mysql, httpd, stress
- What I am trying to achieve: Install wordpress succesfully on Amazon EC2 instance and sync up the wp-content folder to S3 bucket [trying to schedule and automate it].

[image]

Problem Encountered:

- Kindly go through the screenshot of my crontab
- When I manually try to replicate it through CLI, the content are replicated with out any issues
- When I try to use the crontab, it never gets sync'ed.

Note:

- S3-EC2 roles have been attached to the instance.
- I Have made the bucket public [ I am just testing it, it's ok ]

Comment: thanks John for editing, I will be more careful from next time.

Answer (score 0):

The format for a `crontab` in Amazon Linux is:

```
 ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
 │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
 │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
 │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
 │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday)
 │ │ │ │ │
 │ │ │ │ │
 * * * * *  command to execute
```

Your file appears to have an extra `user` field that is probably causing it to fail.

Comment: john, I will be trying this around this week, Thanks for working on this. will keep you updated .